# Get .NET Core JSON Body as dynamic object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My ASP.NET Core endpoint accepts a JSON form as its input and calls a method that expects a dynamic argument. I am attempting to call the method like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult InitializeAction([FromBody] dynamic jsonData)
{
    return this.Ok(this.MyMethod(jsonData));
}
```

When I POST the JSON `{"test": "value"}` to this method, I would expect identical behavior to doing the following:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult InitializeAction([FromBody] dynamic jsonData)
{
    return this.Ok(this.MyMethod(new {test = "value"}));
}
```

However, the JSON value retrieved using the `[FromBody]` parameter does not get converted to a standard .NET dynamic argument, and is instead a `JsonDocument` or `JsonElement` or something along those lines.

How do I receive or serialize the JSON from the HTTP Post as a .NET dynamic object?

Comment: I am aware that I can use `dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData.ToString())` to get what I am looking for. Is there a way to get my intended result without first converting the `jsonData` argument to a string, or is this the right answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The incoming JSON body can be converted to a dynamic object by using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` on the JSON string.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult InitializeAction([FromBody] dynamic jsonData)
{
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData.ToString());
    return this.Ok(this.MyMethod(data));
}
```

Comment: I'd stay away from dynamic as much as possible especially in this case because you can use JObject or ExpandoObject both of which are better suited for this case @MichaelWang 's solution is better

Comment: @mare This question is not about what data type is best for processing JSON. I needed to pass a dynamic object to an existing library and the data I needed to pass was formatted as JSON. I agree that using another data type would be better if I was doing any further processing on the data, but I am not.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE 31/07/2020**

If convert `object` to `ExpandoObject` , you can access `test` directly.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/init")]
    public IActionResult Init([FromBody] dynamic jsonData)
    {
        var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
        var exObjExpandoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonData.ToString(), converter) as dynamic;

        return this.Ok(this.MyMethod(exObjExpandoObject));
    }

    public string MyMethod(dynamic obj)
    {
        return obj.test;
    }
```

[image]

If use `object` , you need to get `value` by `GetProperty`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/init2")]
    public IActionResult InitializeAction([FromBody] dynamic jsonData)
    {
        return this.Ok(this.MyMethod2(jsonData));
    }

    public string MyMethod2(dynamic obj)
    {
        JsonElement value = obj.GetProperty("test");
        return value.ToString();
    }
```

[image]

---

The `ExpandoObject` is a convenience type that allows setting and retrieving dynamic members. It implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` which enables sharing instances between languages in the `DLR`. Because it implements `IDictionary` and `IEnumerable`, it works with types from the `CLR`. This allows an instance of the `ExpandoObject` to cast to `IDictionary`.

To use the ExpandoObject with an arbitrary JSON, you can write the following program:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/init")]
    public IActionResult InitializeAction([FromBody] dynamic jsonData)
    {
        var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
        var exObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonData.ToString(), converter);

        Debug.WriteLine($"exObj.test = {exObj?.test}, type of {exObj?.test.GetType()}") as dynamic;

        return this.Ok(exObj.test);
    }
```

> Screenshots of Test:

[image]

[image]

**Reference**
[Working with the Dynamic Type in C#](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/c-programming/working-with-the-dynamic-type-in-c/)

Comment: Interestingly, I can do the same thing more simply using `dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData.ToString())`. But is doing a dual conversion of the JSON value from the POST to a string and then to a dynamic object really the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: ExpandoObject enables you to add and delete members of its instances at run time and also to set and get values of these members. It  supports dynamic binding, which enables you to use standard syntax like exObj.test

Comment: Those are nice features, but I do not need the functionality of `ExpandoObject`, as once my .NET Core endpoint converts the incoming JSON data, it passes it to a method from an existing .NET library that only needs a dynamic object. I will not be accessing or manipulating the converted result in my own code.

Comment: string jsonData = "{\"test\":\"value\"}";                                                                      
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData);

Comment: I wouldn't use dynamic type on incoming parameters. Rather use ExpandoObject or JObject.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelWang. I am working on a .Net Core Web API and using dynamic. For some reason it was not returning the values, but it was returning the keys. The ExpandoObject fixed the issue.