# Need to create a WepApi controller to handle generic objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, blazor

I have an exising webforms application which references hundreds of SQL views, and displays them out into grids in different places in the application. I'm currently rewriting the application in Blazor Web assembly (which I'm loving btw).

I can create a blazor component to display the contents of whatever enumerable I throw at it.  So all good there.

In my backend (which the old webforms app uses, and the new WebApi I'm creating for serving the Blazor data) I have a service layer which is implemented through generics, and talks to the SQL database via EntityFramework (I have a lot of existing mature code which handles all this for me). I have Entity classes generated off the database (using a PetaPoco like templating tool).

So I have entity classes such as:

- Contact
- Task
- Note
- MailingList

Then I have some entity classes based off my views such as

- VwContactTasks
- VwContactNotes
- VwContactMailingLists

Now, from an architectural perspective I appreciate I can pass the tasks and notes back with the contact entity, but that means my contact entity becomes unwieldly. Tasks are dealt with independantly from Contacts, but when displaying a contact I wand to display a paged grid of all tasks linked to the contact. I know it seems like an antipattern, but I quite like the fact these are composed in the SQL views, as they pull data in from all sorts of linked tables (task_types, dead_line_types, task_status, alert_status etc), and then displayed as is in the UI.

I have code which allows to fire up a service with

```
new Service<VwContactTasks>()
```

which I can then use to get the data using GetAllItems() and add where clauses to filter the data.

So in my WebAPI I have the following controllers:

- ContactController
- TaskController
- NoteController

etc...

What I don't want to do is create

- VwContactTaskController - because there would be hundreds of them

Similarly, I don't want to add GetVwContactTaks(int contactId) endpoints to my contact controller - again there would be hundreds of them..

Ideally, what I'd like to do is create a generic data webapi controller, ie `DataController<TSource>` which I can then call from UI application somehow, but I appreciate that would be next to impossible..

So I did wonder about a data end point where I pass the type and the criteria inside the request. So a request which looks something like:

```
public class SqlViewRequest
{
     Type ViewType   {get;set;}
     Func Criteria {get;set;}
}
```

and a controller with the following end point

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<object>> GetView(SqlViewRequest request)
{
      var service = new Service<[get viewtype from request]>();
      var results = Service.GetAllItems.Where(ViewRequest.Criteria).ToList()
      return Ok(results);
}
```

Is doing something like even possible?? Obviously even with generics the type needs to be apparent at compile time, so I'd have to pass Expression trees or emit IL code to achieve it. But I'd hate to generate mutiple API end points.

I guess the other way to do it, is to emit a System.Data.DataTable from the controller, but that seems yukky.

Comment: Multiple approaches are possible. Please check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163768/get-net-core-json-body-as-dynamic-object , https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/05/10/why-model-binding-to-jobject-from-a-request-doesnt-work-anymore-in-asp-net-core-3-1-and-whats-the-alternative/ with Once you get the request content in the controller, it's a good idea to dispatch the actual exectuion of the filtering requests to handlers with static type checking. Also, be careful if you intend to combine the incoming requests with SQL SELECT statements. Beware of potential SQL injections!

Comment: Are you using any kind of DI framework? Its kind of anti patterny but some like unity support named service resolution. You could resolve them based on the name you provide in your SqlViewRequest object. You would have to register all of them though which isn't great as you've said there's so many

Comment: @AlexeyAdadurov Thanks, it should be firing through the EntityFramework objects, rather than the SQL directly. Injection attacks are less of an issue as it will only be authorised admin users able to hit the end points.

Comment: @Topher thank you.  I'm using the DI in .net core.. It is an antipattern, but the alternative is such a crazy amount of boiler plate  code. Registering all of them might not be an issue, as long as it's a oneliner (I could create the registration using the templating tool I'm already using for generating the Pocos from the db views in the first place - but I'd hate to expand that into creating controllers because it would just be a mess).

Comment: Asp net core doesn't support named service registration by default, but a friend of mine maintaines a library that adds support which might help you... https://github.com/dazinator/Dazinator.Extensions.DependencyInjection . It's pretty straight forward to use. There's a link to a fairly comprehensive docs page from there. There's likely other options, I just know of that one